# VSCode does not show import suggestions of classes starting with underscore in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As described in the title, I cannot get the import suggestions of classes starting with underscore (e.g: _A). Is there any VSCode or Python extension settings that I can modify to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you try to create a module under the workspace folder and the name start with an underscore? Then try to import it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `__all__ = ['_My_Class', 'Name_Of_Other_Classes']` to the top of the file in which _My_Class is located MAY help.
It defines which classes should be imported by default when using the `import file_with__my_class` statement. But even without the `__all__` statement, the import suggestions work by default in my environment, as intended.